# Execute a process as a different user

Tags: php, linux, process, permissions

I understand that calling PHP functions like `exec` and `system` would run the process with the same user as PHP itself, or the web server running it.

Is there *any* way to run executables with PHP as a different user?

Please note that I'm looking for a built-in PHP functionality, I'm well aware of the `sudo` alternatives.

**EDIT:**

I ended up using the [`setid`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28363/123630) flag on the binary to run the executable as root.

Comment: @Dagon I edited the question to distinguish it from the duplicate.

Comment: then no, there is no php function to change the OS user. just imagine the security implications?